# Как распарсить объект PendingIntent, приведённый к типу String

Tags: java, строки, классы, pendingintent

Имеется объект класса PendingIntent, приведенный к строке методом toString (). Его нужно распарсить обратно в объект PendingIntent и вызвать! Каким образом можно это осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

`toString ()` не является методом, который сериализует объект. Поэтому получить обратно объект из него нельзя. Однако вы можете использовать значения выводимые в строке (зависит от имплементации) для создания  нового объекта с этими значениями, если конечно поля можно инициализировать с помощью конструктора или мутаторов.

Comment: Можете поподробнее объяснить алгоритм такого преобразования?

Comment: Берете строку, парсите там названия полей и их значения, создаете объект, присваиваете им полученные значения, после сравнения обектов методом `equals()` должно возвращаться `true`.